# RabbitMQ Management Plugin - Connection Timeout

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, ubuntu-14.04

There are similar questions like mine but I couldn't find the correct solution for my specific issue. I try to install RabbitMQ including the management plugin on a virtual machine. I get `Connection Timeout` when I try to access the interface.

Some details about my virtual machine, it may helps:

OS:  Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64)

netstat -nptl | grep 15672

```
3:tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31120/beam
```

rabbitmq-plugins list

```
[e*] amqp_client                       3.5.4
[e*] mochiweb                          2.7.0-rmq3.5.4-git680dba8
[E*] rabbitmq_management               3.5.4
[E*] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.5.4
[e*] rabbitmq_web_dispatch             3.5.4
[e*] webmachine                        1.10.3-rmq3.5.4-gite9359c7
```

rabbitmqctl status

```
{running_applications,
    [{rabbitmq_management,"RabbitMQ Management Console","3.5.4"},
    ...
```

/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@local.log

```
...
=INFO REPORT==== 14-Sep-2015::20:09:31 ===
Management plugin started. Port: 15672
...
=INFO REPORT==== 14-Sep-2015::20:09:31 ===
Server startup complete; 6 plugins started.
* rabbitmq_management
* rabbitmq_web_dispatch
* webmachine
* mochiweb
* rabbitmq_management_agent
* amqp_client
...
```

Tried but same issue like before:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl stop
sudo invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you will find the solution direct after you ask something. The problem was a non-forwarded port. After I forwarded port 5672 and 15672 it works.

Answer (score 0):

this error `{:query, :rabbit@rabbitmq, {:badrpc, :timeout}}`  can occur because rabbitmq can't resolve the node name default is `rabbit`

### Solution:

1. login into rabbitmq instance
2. add `127.0.0.1 rabbit` into /etc/hosts file
3. run commands with `--node rabbit@rabbitmq` flag